# Problems with Datetime Periods In es-AR browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime

i have a problem with datetime using javascript in es-AR browser.

It is a select that changes period every 15 days or so.
The problem is when I want to spend a date in a browser in Argentine Spanish, given that the format of:
M / d / yyyy to d / M / yyyy then it breaks my date.
I already tried an "If (es-AR)" but it is not the best solution for me. I would like to have a good answer about some feasible solution.
Here I leave the code thank you very much.

```js
    function InitializeDropdownlistOfFirstOption(dropdownName, step) {
    $('#fromPeriodValidation').hide();
    $('#toPeriodValidation').hide();
    var dropdownList = $('#' + dropdownName);
    var timeperiod = dropdownList.val();
    var reg = new RegExp("\\.|-", "g");
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
    if (String(userLang) == 'es-AR') {
        alert(String(cultureInfo));
        var formattimeperiod = timeperiod.replace(reg, "/");
        if (formattimeperiod.split("/")[0] > 12) {
            var tempDay = formattimeperiod.split("/")[0];
            var tempMonth = formattimeperiod.split("/")[1];
            var tempYear = formattimeperiod.split("/")[2];
            formattimeperiod = tempMonth + "/" + tempDay + "/" + tempYear;
        }
        timeperiod = formattimeperiod;
    }

    var timeperioddate = new Date(timeperiod);
    
    var month = timeperioddate.getMonth();
    var day = timeperioddate.getDate();
    var year = timeperioddate.getFullYear();
    var option;
    dropdownList.get(0).remove(0);

    if (day <= 15) {
        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                day = new Date(new Date(year, (month + 1) % 12, 1).getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24).getDate();
                option = new Date(year, month, day).format(pattern);
                dropdownList.prepend("<option value='" + option + "'>" + option + "</option>");     
                break;
            case -1:
                month--;
                if (month < 1) {
                    month += 12;
                    year--;
                }
                if (month == 12) {
                    day = 31;
                } else {
                    day = new Date(new Date(year, (month + 1) % 12, 1).getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24).getDate();
                }
                option = new Date(year, month, day).format(pattern);
                dropdownList.prepend("<option value='" + option + "'>" + option + "</option>");
                break;
        }
    } else {
        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                month++;
                if (month > 12) {
                    month = 1;
                    year++;
                }
                if (month == 12) {
                    day = 31;
                } else {
                    day = new Date(new Date(year, (month) % 12, 1).getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24).getDate();
                }
                option = new Date(year, month, 15).format(pattern);
                dropdownList.prepend("<option value='" + option + "'>" + option + "</option>");
                break;
            case -1:
                option = new Date(year, month, 15).format(pattern);
                dropdownList.prepend("<option value='" + option + "'>" + option + "</option>");
                break;
        }
    }
    dropdownList.get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="timeperiod" id="timeperiod">
                <div style="width: 40%;float: left">
                    <label class="lblTime"><b>From Time Period</b></label>
                    <form class="form">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button" onclick="InitializeDropdownlistOfFirstOption('drpfromdatePeriod', -1)">< </button>
                        <select name="drpfromdatePeriod" class="drpdateperiod" id="drpfromdatePeriod" onchange="SelectPeriod('drpfromdatePeriod')"></select>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button" onclick="InitializeDropdownlistOfFirstOption('drpfromdatePeriod', 1)">> </button>
                        <img src="@Url.ImportContent("~/Content/images/time_period_calendar.png")" class="imgCalendar" id="imgFromdate" />
                    </form>
                    <label class="lblTime"><b>To Time Period</b></label>
                    <form class="form">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button" onclick="InitializeDropdownlistOfFirstOption('drptodatePeriod', -1)">< </button>
                        <select name="drptodatePeriod" class="drpdateperiod" id="drptodatePeriod" onchange="SelectPeriod('drptodatePeriod')"></select>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button" onclick="InitializeDropdownlistOfFirstOption('drptodatePeriod', 1)">> </button>
                        <img src="@Url.ImportContent("~/Content/images/time_period_calendar.png")" class="imgCalendar" id="imgTodate" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbVat" value="Only return expense receipts with VAT" onclick="SelectVat(this.checked)"/>
                    <label class="lblTime" id="lbVatMessage"> <b>Only return expense receipts with VAT</b></label>
                    <img src="@Url.ImportContent("~/Content/images/info.gif")" class="imgInfo" title="If this checkbox is selected, the application will only return receipts for expenses with VAT." />
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

I appreciate any help :D
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tRBC.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0UVA.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! `but it is not the best solution for me` ... why? Is it not working? Errors popping up? Not a clean code? How can we improve your code?

Comment: Because in addition to Argentine Spanish there are many more countries where the date format changes. And I would not like to have to do an if for each country that reports the error in the format. I would like something more global that serves any date.

Comment: Jhonpol, you'd be better off using some black-box libraries for that. The issue of time formats is way too complex to be globally fixed by a few lines of code.

Comment: I googled it, and found momentjs . Don't know if `moment.parseZone()` would fit your needs, but give it a try.

Comment: @EricWu well I'll try it, thanks so much

Comment: I'll be posting an answer with that. If it does fit your needs, accept it :)

Comment: Okey, waiting for..

Answer (score 0):

Trying to globally solve the time format problem by yourself would not be the best approach.

Libraries such as [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com) implement methods such as `moment.parseZone()`, which appears to solve these problems for you.